# Error when using `inert` attribute with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dialog, create-react-app, html-inert

I have created a vanilla create-react-app using the Typescript template.
I have added the line:

```
<dialog inert></dialog>
```

And the app won't even run because typescript is throwing an error saying:

> ERROR in src/App.tsx:9:15
> TS2322: Type '{ children: never[]; inert: true; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<DialogHTMLAttributes, HTMLDialogElement>'.
> Property 'inert' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<DialogHTMLAttributes, HTMLDialogElement>'.

I would like to fix it instead of ignore it, but even ignoring doesn't seem to work.

```
// @ts-ignore
return (<dialog inert></dialog>);
```

Answer (score 5):

One low-effort way to work around the fact that [React (as of writing) does not yet have type definitions for the `inert` attribute](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/24730) is to wrap it into an object and then destructure it back onto your element:

```
<dialog
    // A silly workaround to use `inert` until https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/24730 is merged.
    {...{ inert: isInert ? '' : undefined }}
>
    Oh, hi
</dialog>
```

While positively silly, this should short-circuit any specific TypeScript and ESLint complaints and allow you to use it. Note that JSX itself might still complain at you if this is the *only* attribute on your element, *and* your element has no children. Why exactly one would create an empty, inert element beats me, but `sips tea` that's none of my business.

---

A slightly more robust solution would be a combination of a few things.

To make TypeScript happy, you can add (or add to) a `declarations.d.ts` file for your project, stubbing in a temporary definition for the `inert` attribute:

```
declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
    /**
     * Indicates that the browser will ignore this element and its descendants,
     * preventing some interactions and hiding it from assistive technology.
     * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inert
     * @todo Remove this stub declaration after https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/24730 is merged.
     */
    inert?: '';
  }
}
```

If you're using ESLint, you can add an exception for `inert` in your config file (`.eslintrc` or similar) via [the `react/no-unknown-property` rule](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unknown-property.md):

```js
rules: {
    // Allows the use of the `inert` attribute until https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/24730 is merged.
    'react/no-unknown-property': ['error', { ignore: ['inert'] }],
}
```

---

In both of these solutions, we're forced to use the slightly odd syntax of passing `inert` an empty string (for `true`) or `undefined` (for `false`). This feels a bit clunky compared to attributes like `disabled`, which can directly accept boolean values. Unfortunately, using booleans this way is syntactical sugar that React adds to supported attributes, so we won't get that particular benefit for `inert` until it's supported natively.

Answer (score 4):

The type hasn't been added yet to the React TypeScript definitions. There is a draft PR [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/60822) in the works, so if that get's merged should work.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to override the types in my app now?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your global type definitions:

```
declare namespace React {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
    inert?: ''
  }
}
```

And instead of using it as a boolean, use as an empty string:

```
<dialog inert="" />
```

Or:

```
<dialog inert={shouldBeInert ? '' : undefined} />
```